# Target child of <li> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a check list. When you click on the li element, the child div of that element should become visible.

```
<div id="list_one">
    <h2>LIST TITLE</h2>
    <div id="line"></div>
    <ul>
        <li id="1-1"><div class="blue_line"></div><div class="circle"></div>TASK ONE</li>
        <li id="1-2"><div class="blue_line"></div><div class="circle"></div>TASK TWO</li>
        <li id="1-3"><div class="blue_line"></div><div class="circle"></div>TASK THREE</li>
        <li id="1-4"><div class="blue_line"></div><div class="circle"></div>TASK FOUR</li>
        <li id="1-5"><div class="blue_line"></div><div class="circle"></div>TASK FIVE</li>
        <li id="1-6"><div class="blue_line"></div><div class="circle"></div>TASK SIX</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".blue_line").css("visibility","hidden");

    $("li").click(function() {
        var id = this.id;
        console.log(id);
        $(id).children().css("visibility","visible");
    });
});
```

Comment: You can just do `$(this).children().css("visibility","visible");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to use the id like that. Use $(this) to access the LI:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".blue_line").css("visibility","hidden");
    $("li").click(function() {
        $(this).children().css("visibility","visible");
    });
});
```

As pointed out elsewhere, the cause was using `$(id)` when you needed to do `$('#' + id)` to make it a valid jQuery ID selector

Comment: Didn't want to create a separate answer, but I created this fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/q4pFX/

Comment: @xDaevax: Thanks. That was kind of you :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the `#` character:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".blue_line").css("visibility","hidden");
    $("li").click(function() {
        var id = this.id;
        console.log(id);
        $("#" + id).children().css("visibility","visible");
    });
});
```

But as already mentioned, it makes much more sense to use `$(this)` within the event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".blue_line").css("visibility","hidden");
    $("li").click(function() {
        $(this).children().css("visibility","visible");
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as it will let me.

Comment: While this is the issue but it's not the best answer, much better after edit

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if I got you right but:

```
$("li").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C6Qav/1/

"When an item is clicked add a checked class which shows a blue line".

It is nicer that way - less intrusive to use a class and you can do anything you want in the css file to the li element when it has the `.checked` class (not adding styles directly with javascript to the element is recommended).

PS Avoid using IDs everwhere.